# How to print vector's data

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've searched a lot over the internet, and couldent find simple examples to print vector's data..

I tried to print it like an array, though it didnt worked...

Here's what I tried :

```
using namespace std ;
.....
const int MAX = 255 ;

vector <string> testersName[MAX];
cout << testersName[i] << endl;
```

The error is only in the cout line, the first line is getting complied and everything goes well..

I got data inside testersName, though Im getting this error :

> "Error 1   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::vector<_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

Comment: 1. You want to call the constructor, not declare an array. 2. The homework tag is deprecated.

Comment: Are you creating an array of vectors and trying to print one of those vectors, or do you think you are trying to print a string from within your vector?

Comment: @CashCow I'm trying to create a vector in a side of MAX (255)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vector <string> testersName[MAX];` declares an array of vectors, try simply `vector <string> testersName(MAX);` - this declares a vector with `MAX` elements.

Comment: if I change ` vector <string> testersName[MAX]; ` to ` vector <string> testersName(max) ` It does an error to me...

Comment: @AmitM9S6 you do realize no one can help you if you don't tell us what the errors are, right? Regardless of these new errors, the code should be with `()` instead of `[]`, like I pointed out.

Comment: I will try to fix them by my self, (I guess their releated to the other part of the project)... If I wont be able to fix it by my self, Ill post another comment here... Thanks!

Comment: @AmitM9S6 actually, if they're unrelated to this problem, post a new question. Comments aren't really the place to ask new questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to **iterate** over the vector's elements and then brint each one :

```
vector <string> testersName;
// Fill your vector
for (int i = 0; i < testersName.size(); ++i) {
    cout << testersName[i] << endl;
}
```

Moreover, I don't think the line `vector <string> testersName[MAX];` does what you think it does. It is not necessary to give a size to the vector because it grows dynamically when you fill it. If you still want to give a size, use parenthesis : `(MAX)`

Comment: @AmitM9S6 How do you fill your vector?

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to print a vector is to use some kind of wrapper:

Let's start off with:

```
template< typename T >
class ConstVecFormat
{
   private:
      std::vector<T> const& vec_;
      const std::string prefix_, delim_, suffix_;

   public:
      explicit ConstVecFormat( std::vector<T> const& vec, prefix="", delim=",", suffix="" ) :
          vec_(vec), prefix_(prefix), delim_(delim), suffix_(suffix_)
      {
      }

      std::ostream& print( std::ostream& os ) const
      {
         typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator iter = vec_.begin(), end=vec_.end();
         os << prefix_;
         if( iter != end )
              os << *iter;
         else 
           while( ++iter != end )
           {
             os << delim_ << *iter;
           }

         os << suffix_;
         return os;
      }
 };

 template< typename T >
 std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, ConstVecFormat<T> const& format )
 {
     return format.print( os );
 }
```

This is heading towards being a duplicate of a previous topic where we enhanced this template a lot to produce one more generic for printing collections.